# Having trouble with structs in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I created a vector struct and an `addVector` and `subVector` functions. I also created a print vector function.

I need to create 4 vector instances: two for input, two for output (one for the addition and one for the subtraction). I need to call `printVector` to print the result from `addVector` and the result from `subVector`. I think most of it is correct. I am just not sure what to do.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
} VECTOR;

VECTOR addVector(VECTOR *addOne, VECTOR *addTwo) {
    double addX = addOne->x + addTwo->x;
    double addY = addOne->y + addTwo->y;
    double addZ = addOne->z + addTwo->z;
};

VECTOR subVector(VECTOR *subOne, VECTOR *subTwo){
    double subX = subOne->x - subTwo->x;
    double subY = subOne->y - subTwo->y;
    double subZ = subOne->z - subTwo->z;
};

void printVector(VECTOR *printVector) {
    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf\n", printVector->x, printVector->y, printVector->z);
};

void main() {
    VECTOR A;
    VECTOR B;
    VECTOR C = addVector(&A, &B);      
    VECTOR D = subVector(&A, &B);

    printf("Enter three doubles.\n");
    scanf_s("%lf %lf %lf", &A.x, &A.y, &A.z);

    addVector(&A, &B);

    printVector(&C);

    subVector(&A, &B);
    printVector(&D);

    system("pause");
};
```

Comment: when you declare C and D, you should call addVector and subVector respectively.

Comment: Functions `addVector` and `subVector` *appear* to do something, but discard their result. No `struct` is returned by the functions, alternatively there is no target argument passed.

Comment: A good compiler would have warned you about the problem with your code.

Comment: You have another problem with your code. You use `A` and `B` before you've initialized them.

Comment: To add to @Barmar's response, if you use a crappy compiler that doesn't warn you about your errors, then using pretty much any debugger would have answered your questions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute the values of the `VECTOR` coordinates in `addVector` and `subVector`, but you do not return a `VECTOR` structure.

Here is how to do it, and also note that since the `VECTOR` arguments are not modified, the pointers should be `const` qualified to underscore this property:

```
VECTOR addVector(const VECTOR *addOne, const VECTOR *addTwo) {
    VECTOR add;
    add.x = addOne->x + addTwo->x;
    add.y = addOne->y + addTwo->y;
    add.z = addOne->z + addTwo->z;
    return add;
}

VECTOR subVector(const VECTOR *subOne, const VECTOR *subTwo) {
    VECTOR sub;
    sub.x = subOne->x - subTwo->x;
    sub.y = subOne->y - subTwo->y;
    sub.z = subOne->z - subTwo->z;
    return sub;
}

void printVector(const VECTOR *printVector) {
    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf\n", printVector->x, printVector->y, printVector->z);
}
```

In your `main` function, you use vectors `A` and `B` before initializing them or reading their values from the user. Modify the code this way:

```
void main() {
    VECTOR A = { 0, 0, 0 };
    VECTOR B = { 0, 0, 0 };
    VECTOR C, D;

    printf("Enter three doubles for A\n");
    scanf_s("%lf %lf %lf", &A.x, &A.y, &A.z);

    printf("Enter three doubles for B\n");
    scanf_s("%lf %lf %lf", &B.x, &B.y, &B.z);

    C = addVector(&A, &B);
    printVector(&C);

    D = subVector(&A, &B);
    printVector(&D);

    system("pause");
}
```

Finally, do not put a `;` after the body of your functions.

Note also that you should enable all compiler warnings as it can help avoid silly bugs such as the above. Use `gcc -Wall -W` or `clang -Weverything` for command line compilers, and increase the warning level in the Visual Studio IDE if you use that.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning here that passing by pointer-to-const is preferable

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just started coding in school.

Answer (score 0):

`addVector` and `subVector` compute the components of the new vector, but don't actually return a new vector.  But then, you call `addVector` and `subVector` and ignore the return value, so at least you are consistent.

Comment: Not really consistent, he uses the return value in `VECTOR C = addVector(&A, &B);`